# Snscrape error. ScraperException: 4 requests

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

**I do scraping with snscrape with code like this:**

```py
maxTweets = 2000

tweets_list2 = []

for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('Desa Garut since:2022-01-06 until:2022-12-01').get_items()):
    if i>maxTweets:
        break
    tweets_list2.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.username, tweet.user.location, tweet.sourceUrl, tweet.lang, tweet.hashtags, tweet.links, tweet.replyCount, tweet.retweetCount, tweet.likeCount, tweet.quoteCount, tweet.media, tweet.content.encode("utf-8")])
```

**But getting error problem:**

```
ScraperException: 4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&include_ext_is_blue_verified=1&include_ext_verified_type=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_ext_limited_action_results=false&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_ext_collab_control=true&include_ext_views=true&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=KongClubNFT+since%3A2022-01-06+until%3A2022-12-01&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&include_ext_edit_control=true&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo%2CeditControl%2Ccollab_control%2Cvibe failed, giving up.
```

**Please help as soon as possible**

I've uninstalled snscrape and reinstalled it, but still the error. is there any other way to fix it?